# Question about output of a function

Tags: function-construction, output

I'm pretty new to programming in Mathematica and have a question. I wrote this function to factorise large numbers. The outputs are almost as expected, but I don't understand where the null's come from. How do I get rid of those? The first example should output 1229, the second should output nothing. Any help appreciated.

```
In[87]:= pollardrho[n_] := Module[{x, y, d},
x = 2;
y = 2;
d = 1;
g[x_] := Mod[x^2 + 1, n];
While[d == 1,
    x = g[x];
    y = g[g[y]];
    d = GCD[Abs[x - y], n];
If[d == n, , d]]


In[88]:= pollardrho[2896753]

Out[88]= 1229 Null

In[89]:= pollardrho[17]

Out[89]= Null^2
```

Comment: They're probably from the first part of th If which returns nothing.

Comment: How, though? I mean, only one of the two statements in the If part should be evaluated, did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: You have mis-matched parentheses. The If is inside the While loop, so gets evaluated more than once.

Comment: It looks like you made a typo, maybe you forgot the semi-colon after the `While` loop. It's hard to be sure as the code you posted here is not the same as the code in your notebook (I can tell because the code here will not run at all due to missing brackets).

Answer (score 1):

Although achieving the desired output requires only minor modifications to the `Module`, 
I provide it here in a modestly more compact form:

```
pollardrho[n_] := Module[{x = 2, y = 2, d = 1}, g[x_] := Mod[x^2 + 1, n]; 
  While[d == 1, x = g[x]; y = g[g[y]]; d = GCD[Abs[x - y], n]];
  If[d == n, "Null", d]]

pollardrho[2896753]
(* 1229 *)

pollardrho[17]
(* Null *)
```

Comment: `pollardrho[17]` is supposed to return `Null` though

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding on my part.  I believe that the modified `Modeule` does the job.  Note that I put `Null` in quotes, so that you could see it in the output. Otherwise, `pollardrho[17]` produces no visible output.